# Google Analytics - Is it possible to have different filters in each tab in the same custom report?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

I'm building a custom report using google analytics, a report that has 3 different tabs.

I want to apply a different filter to each tab but when I change the filter in any of them, it automatically changes the filter in the other tabs.

Is there a way of doing this or do I necessarily need to create another custom report to apply different filters?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about the Google analytics website and is not programing related might be better suited for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately not. Creating a Dashboard will allow you to have all your reports - with their individual filters - in one place.

Answer (score 1):

No. This is not possible. You need to create separate custom reports.